# SAS - aggregating daily content with same day occurrences

Tags: sas

I have daily data, not completely consecutive (i.e., not all days are present in a week) and I need to convert it to weekly totals. The catch is that the data pertains to transactions such that there are multiple observations with the same day. Using the following PROC EXPAND procedure results in an error "The value of the ID variable, FixtureDate=04JAN2011, at observation number 2 in data set RAW.VLCC2011 is the same as the previous observation":

```
    PROC EXPAND DATA = raw.VLCC2011 OUT = raw.VLCC2011_wkly FROM= Day TO = Week;
    convert FixtureCargoSize/ OBSERVED=TOTAL method=aggregate;
    ID FixtureDate;
    run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with `proc sql`. You could also do something similar with a data step.

```
proc sql;
 create table VLCC2011_wkly as
  select intnx('week', date, 0, 'end') as week, sum(FixtureCargoSize) as FixtureCargoSizeTotal
  from VLCC2011
  group by calculated week;
quit;
```

The `intnx` function takes a date and moves it to some other date. In this case, it takes any date and moves it to the last day of the week. Summing over all dates that have the same end-of-week date in this way will give you want you want.

Comment: Hi Itzy, Not sure I have understood this. I tried the code as above with date as "&FixtureDate"d and the result one row: the sum of all the values in the data set. See my edited version to show how I solved it (the long way).

Comment: In `intnx()`, you don't want `date` to be a constant (which it is if you use a macro variable). It should just be the name of the date variable you have in your data. Based on your code below though, I'm not sure what FixtureDate is -- is it a SAS date? For my code to work, it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used PROC EXPAND. However the error message tells you that it doesn't like that there are multiple observations per ID value. Maybe you need to pre-process the input data set RAW.VLCC2011 such that there is at most one observation per FIXTUREDATE.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it (the long way):

```
data raw.VLCC2011_wkly;
set raw.VLCC2011;
IF FixtureDay < 8 then FixtureWeek = 1;
IF FixtureDay > 7 and FixtureDay < 15 then FixtureWeek = 2;
IF FixtureDay > 14 and FixtureDay < 23 then FixtureWeek = 3;
IF FixtureDay > 22 and FixtureDay < 30 then FixtureWeek = 4;
IF FixtureDay > 29 and FixtureDay < 32 then FixtureWeek = 5;
run;

proc sql;
create table raw.VLCC2011_wkly1 as
select FixtureMonth, FixtureDay, FixtureWeek, FixtureCargoSize,                                   sum(FixtureCargoSize) as CargoSizeTotal
from raw.VLCC2011_wkly 
group by FixtureMonth, FixtureWeek
Order by FixtureMonth, FixtureWeek, FixtureDay;
quit;
```